# Getting WordPress user in codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I want to ask is there any way to get the WordPress users with CodeIgniter? I want to build an application in CodeIgniter in which I want my all WordPress user to login in my CodeIgniter application with the credentials of WordPress user login!! Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the WordPress and the CodeIgniter systems are both on the same domain you could use the `wp_login` hook to add a cookie upon successful login then check for this cookie in your CodeIgniter application.

Comment: The domain will be like www.example.com and the CodeIgniter domain will be like www.example.com/codeigniter